# Complex Array Query in Ecto (Elixir)

Tags: sql, elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I have a complex SQL query :

```
    select count(*) as tag_count, ut.tag
    from doc_tags_array, 
       lateral unnest(doc_tags_array.tags) as ut(tag)
    group by ut.tag
    order by tag_count desc limit 5;
```

Result is :

```
tag_count,tag
3,yellow
2,red
2,blue
1,green
1,orange
```

But I don't know how to 'translate' it in Ecto DSL. For example, how to have multiple `from` ?

Thank you,

Comment: I believe this is equivalent to your `from`: `DocTags |> join(:inner_lateral, [dta], ut in fragment("unnest(?)", dta.tags))`. I don't have the rest of the schema and data to actually try the whole thing, but this might help.

Comment: I see your point, but the generated query is not valid : `INNER JOIN LATERAL (unnest(a0."tag_list")) AS f` and not `INNER JOIN LATERAL unnest(a0.tag_list) AS f1`